# What's the services/running processes manager in Mac OS X?

Tags: services

I installed MySQL but I am unable to see if it is running or has stopped. How do I see what are the currently running services corresponding to the "Services" interface in Windows?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For most of the "services" (called Daemons or Agents documented by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)) you can check:

In terminal: `$ sudo launchctl list`

For example only MySQL you can filter the output of the command above, like `sudo launchctl list | grep -i mysql`. Note `-i` is to make the filter case insensitive.

These also can be controlled with a GUI examples are  [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) and [Launch Control](https://soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/).

There are some other "services", that will install themselves in:

```
/Library/StartupItems
```

For those, there is a command like
`$ ps -ef |grep /Library/StartupItems` to view whether it is loaded and running. But there isn't a generic mechanism to stop, start or restart.

In which category your MySQL installation falls is impossible to say, as your question is lacking details on what exactly you have installed, what its source is, how it was installed, etcetera.

Comment: Manually deleting files from /Library/StartupItems folder worked

Answer (score 11):

The application "Activity Monitor" is located in /Applications/Utilities and will display all processes similar to the Unix command 'top'.

Comment: Note: By default it'll only show processes you own. You should switch it to show all processes in the `View` menu.

Comment: This is not a valid answer. OP is asking for a list "corresponding to the "Services" interface in Windows". The Activity Monitor and top simply show the currently running processes. A process like Chrome and a service like sshd are very different and the essence of the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, cat concatenates or displays /dev/null  which is the bit bucket or nothing
so `cat /dev/null` shows me nothing.

Try `ps -ef` on the command line. This will show you process status everything full

To just see MySQL run

```
ps -ef | grep -i mysql
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use top in the terminal in osx… I am surprised there is no command line service manager in osx. Wow!

Comment: Doesn't `cat /dev/null` show you all windows services that run on OS X?